# Ansible: regex to find a key and change its value in an XML file

Tags: regex, tags, ansible

I'm using the `lineinfile` module of Ansible to change some values in an XML file.

I have to update values for few of my keys inside that XML file.

For that I need to pass correct regex and make sure that the values are put correctly even if I run the playbook repeatedly it wouldn't add any extra line or value, just add what I need.

Answer (score 5):

You should not manipulate nontrivial XML with regular expressions. Use [ansible-xml](https://github.com/RHInception/ansible-xml) instead.

Comment: Thanks, with this I'm getting error:  ERROR: xml is not a legal parameter in an Ansible task or handler

Comment: Any more suggestions?

Comment: You need to actually install the module before you can use it. Clone the GitHub repository and use `--module-path`. See the documentation for details.

Comment: But it's under GNU license... Any alternative ?